# Unable to ping locally with iptables masquerade wifi repeater

Tags: iptables, raspbian, dnsmasq, hostapd

Okay so my network setup is as follows: I have a router that connects to the internet. Said router is 192.168.1.254. My device has 2 wifi adapters. Wlan0 is 192.168.1.99/24 static. (Dhcpcd) Wlan1 is dhcp configured from the router (192.168.1.78) using a subnet 255.255.255.0.

Wlan0 dns server is 8.8.8.8. i have dnsmasq giving out ips on said device in ranges 192.168.1.100-253. (same subnet)

My iptables are as follows:
(/etc/iptables.ipv4.nat)
https://pastebin.com/n35rNjkF

now for some reason on the device (192.168.1.78) im unable to access the router (192.168.1.254) is there an iptables rule for allowing my device to talk to the gateway? Or am i missing something else? WAN is working perfectly. Also an important note is that my phone can ping locally with the same setup just fine, so that tells me the device is where the problem is.

dnsmasq.conf:
https://pastebin.com/9teicmx1

hostapd.conf:
https://pastebin.com/QUpYhLNE

dhcpcd.conf:
https://pastebin.com/uWiJKqnW

rc.local:
https://pastebin.com/LSXbAuX9

/etc/init.d/hostapd:
https://pastebin.com/sytcd56C

/etc/default/hostapd/:
https://pastebin.com/AZbREKY4

ifconfig:
https://pastebin.com/xifJvTu0

ping:
https://pastebin.com/TBWdszU0

route -n:
https://pastebin.com/SV7AHk3g

traceroute to google and router:
`pi@unknown1:~ $ traceroute 192.168.1.254
traceroute to 192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.99 (192.168.1.99)  3157.926 ms !H  3157.750 ms !H  3157.701 ms !H
pi@unknown1:~ $ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (172.217.1.238), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254)  5.377 ms  5.312 ms  5.351 ms
[snip]`

to whom it may concern, the real cloud in this diagram is the ATT modem/router.

My goal is to be able to repeat the main att router with wlan1 (with the client for... lets call it network1 on wlan1) network2 is repeating network1, network2 is wlan0. Wlan0 is its own access point. I would like to be able to access ftp and local intranet on network1 through network2. Network1 has the apache server and ftp server i am trying to access. The repeater itself (wlan0) also needs internet access. This is why i have wlan1 (the second net adapter) so that it can forward network1's internet to network2

Comment: You'll have to give ALL your rules on the router, with: `iptables-save -c`. I bet it's simply the router not allowing it

Comment: If that were the case then my phone wouldnt be able to access locally either, but it can. :( (Ill post logs shortly)

Comment: SInce there's ACCEPT everywhere and no DROP anywhere, I was wrong. So the problem is elsewhere, but no information given this far allows me to pinpoint it. You should really edit the answer with additional informations, and not put it in comments, to get a chance that other people can review the question correctly. You should also put precise, reproducible examples of what does or doesn't work (ping? provide the ping command. web access? then use a curl command. if device allows it or else something easy to reproduce)

Comment: You are using two devices on the same LAN , so there's an access conflict between them. it's not clear why you're doing this. Can you explain *why* you're using two cards? Are you trying to serve an other LAN and be between this other LAN and the router? If that's the case the two LANs should be separate. If that's not... give explanations on your actual goal (not just issue). Is the word "router" always talking about the same system, or are there two systems you both name "router" ? Also if ping works over ipv6 chances are you have zero protection against ipv6 access (no NAT there...)

Comment: Updated question to clearer define the goal. I figured as long as network2 was on the same subnet and ip range it would share internet from network1. As far as ipv4 conflicts go ive made sure there are none with static ips on the router from network1.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell this, but try to have somebody near you reread what is written, and ask if the meaning is clear... An ascii picture would be so much better. _Anyway_ I think you have some misconceptions about how network are working. You can't have two identical networks on two cards and expect them to work together. You cheated on the metric so only the lower metric (303 => wlan0) works, then you want to use the other card: no go. Because you made links and didn't complete the question with the informations _in the questions_, all informations are hard to read

Comment: I'm stopping here for this question. I think you should first read documentation to grasp IPv4 and what do networks and  router mean in this context